# Haml multiline comments and if-elsif-else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, haml

I have the following code.

```
- if specializations.count <= 0
  .alert.alert-warning
    Warning message

-# - elsif agency.offers_limit >= agency.offers.count
-#   .alert.alert-warning
-#     Warning message

- else
  = render 'form'
```

In this case I receive `Got "else" with no preceding "if"`. How else can I comment part of already commented code so that `- else ...` is processed properly?

If I comment code like this:

```
- if specializations.count <= 0
  .alert.alert-warning
    Warning message

-# - elsif agency.offers_limit >= agency.offers.count
  .alert.alert-warning
    Warning message

- else
  = render 'form'
```

I have no error, but `- else ...` is not processed and no form is rendered.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the code that you are posting. HAML uses [nested comments](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#haml_comments_), so the two code pieces you posted here are equal. Perhaps there is something else going on. I would suggest that you get syntax highlighting for HAML in whatever text editor you are using.

Comment: With syntax highlighting everything is OK. That block I want to comment - returns TRUE, so it should be processed if present. If I comment it, I expect it to be skipped, so as the result - form should be rendered. But the form is only rendered when I delete the commented block.

Comment: OK, so perhaps it's still being processed. Try removing the extra hyphen so it looks like `-# elsif agency.offers_limit >= agency.offers.count` and see if it works.

Comment: No, that does not help - everything is simply ignored. It seems I've just found solution - will post as answer in a few minutes.

Comment: This actually looks like a bug in Haml’s parser. I’ve opened a bug report here: https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/815

Answer (score 6):

The code that should not be processed within `if - elsif - else` statement should be **indented**. So, if in my case I want to skip `elsif` statement, my code should look like this:

```
- if specializations.count <= 0
  .alert.alert-warning
    Warning message 

  -# - elsif agency.offers_limit >= agency.offers.count
  -#  .alert.alert-warning
  -#    Warning message

- else
  = render 'form'
```

or like this (to preserve correct indentation):

```
- if specializations.count <= 0
  .alert.alert-warning
    Warning message 

  -# - elsif agency.offers_limit >= agency.offers.count
    .alert.alert-warning
      Warning message

- else
  = render 'form'
```